# animation keeps on going after completion

Tags: objective-c, animation

I am moving some tiles around(UIlabels really) with animations. This works, but I also want the tiles to return to their original position on animation completion. I get very varied results on this. Sometimes it works great, but authorities it seems to animate the resetting of their position. Here is a sample of my code.

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationLength animations:^{
            for (int c = 0; c<tilesToMove.count; c++) {
                animationMoving = true;
                NSInteger fromTile = [tilesToMove[c][0] integerValue];
                NSInteger toTile = [tilesToMove[c][1] integerValue];
                UILabel *toTile = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:toTile];
                UILabel *fromLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:fromTile];
                fromLabel.frame = CGRectMake(toTile.frame.origin.x, toTile.frame.origin.y, fromLabel.frame.size.width,fromLabel.frame.size.height);
            }

    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             for (int c = 0; c<tilesToMove.count; c++) {
                                 NSInteger fromTile = [tilesToMove[c][0] integerValue];
                                 NSInteger toTile = [tilesToMove[c][1] integerValue];
                                 UILabel *button = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:fromTile+100000];
                                 UILabel *fromLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:fromTile];
                                 fromLabel.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, fromLabel.frame.size.width,fromLabel.frame.size.height);

                             }
                              [self animateMoveCompleted:moveDirection];

                         }


                     }];
```

it looks for the tag of every tile that I want to move in an array, called tilesToMove. This also holds the tag of the tile that I want the first tile to move to(animate to the same position). On completion, I want it to reset to the original position. This always works, but sometimes, it animates the transition. This is not my intention. I only want to animate the first move(which works as intended), not the resetting of the positions(does reset to the right position, but animates).

Does the completion of an animation animate?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: It was selected on the storyboard. I't probably shouldn't be on, since I do my layout in code. I just disabled it, but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Does the completion of an animation animate" the completion block doesn't DO anything.

It is a block of code that will execute when the animation is complete.

If the code inside that block starts another animation then yes it will animate.

Because you have called a method with a name `animate...` then this will be the problem. You need to run a method that doesn't animate the properties. It should just set them if you want to not animate them.

**HINT**

Or you could use a `timeDuration` of 0 if you don't want it to animate.

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought originally. I just get confused when seeing that it does. I guess there is a different problem. Thanks for clearing that up:)

Comment: @runartrollet which different problem? Not sure if you are saying my answer is correct or not? :)

Comment: the animateMoveComplete only refreshes values in the labels, doesn't include anything that can animate. I've checked this by not calling it, does not make a difference.
Your answer is helping a lot, so I think I'll mark this as my answer since I think that is all you can help me with, without really seeing more of my project. The problem with the animating after completion is still there. But I guess something else must be causing it. Can't understand what though.

Comment: I did figure it out. There was a different animation going on, animating something different. I guess this also made this animate. but thanks:)